# Convert List<Object> to List<List<Object>> by Object's field. Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, dictionary, filter

I have a list of objects:

`val list = List<Example>`

`data class Example( val date: String, val color: Int, val startTime: String )`

I want to get List<List> where inner lists are sorted by Example.date.
I think it needs to use a map func with sort by date, but I can't figure out how to do it. Any advice, please

Comment: But what would be the outer list? How do you want to make a flat list a deep one? Could you provide an example?

Comment: @JekisOsipov Why is _date_ a String? Why is _startTime_ a String? What is the date and time formats of these strings if they indeed must be strings? Also, please format the code as 'source code'.

Comment: @broot Every example object contains "date" property. According the date, every list have to contain all objects with current date. Have I explained in enough detail?

Comment: @lukas.j I get JSON, that was converted to data class with such string fields

Comment: @JekisOsipov but what is the date format in those strings? You could possibly use a simple sort on the strings, but it's not possible with every format (for instance with illogical US formats like `MM/dd/yyyy`). Also, even if those are strings in JSON, most JSON libraries would allow you to use real date types and convert the strings automatically based on a format (using more or less custom deserializers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you not only want to sort by date but also to group elements with the same date.

Assuming the date format is something logical from bigger to smaller units, like [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (`yyyy-MM-dd`), you could directly sort the strings without parsing them to dates:

```kotlin
val list = TODO("provide some List<Example>")
val result = list.groupBy { it.date }.values.sortedBy { it[0].date }
```

The `groupBy` will return a `Map<String, List<Example>>` where key is a date and each value is a list that contains `Example`s with the same date. Using `.values`, we only get the values from the map, so a list of lists. Then the `sortedBy` will sort the lists by the date of their first element (which is the date of all their elements, since they were grouped like this).

Comment: Actually, after grouping we get a map.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I guess I should have got more sleep last night :facepalm: